# Attempting to recycle a Mac external HDD for Windows and Ubuntu use

Tags: mount, hard-drive

The external HDD was being used as a back-up for the Mac laptop. After formatting the external via the Mac,  first as  as FAT and then exFAT, I have been unable to get the disk to work via Ubuntu. GParted does not reveal the external USB HDD.

I tried the following via Ubuntu Terminal:

sudo fdisk -l
will list all available drives and partitions. Find the drive/partition you want to mount, and run:
sudo mkdir /mnt/disk
sudo mount /dev/(insert disk/partition here) /mnt/disk

The results are below:

```
Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1           2 398297087 398297086 189.9G  b W95 FAT32
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/disk
$ sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/disk
    mount: /mnt/disk: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

What should I try next please?

Comment: Gparted, first of all, does not support exFAT.  Secondly, have you install the `exfat-utils` into your Ubuntu so that the system can mount it and do other things to the filing system?

Comment: I would try NTFS

Comment: You would need to explicitly add the -tvfat switch to the mount for the FAT32 mount to succeed.